# Is it common practice to store objects internally as json using gson?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, gson

I had difficulty finding a clear explanation or documentation of the best way to store objects internally or at all.

Is it common practice to convert objects to json to store them?  Is there a better way to do this?

I have a relatively simple objects with some string fields and other object fields containing primitive types if it matters.

Comment: Maybe room library it's all you need

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.    What do you mean by "store objects internally"?   To me, "store" implies persistence, which is external.

Comment: Where are you storing the objects? Are you using a flat file? Or are you using a database?

Comment: I meant for android, storing in internal storage, as opposed to external, sharedpreferences, and database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways and options to save objects "internally" which your app can accessed.

1. [Realm](https://realm.io/) - This one is a good starter, has a good documentation and has a very straight forward approach on saving and getting back the object.

A good way to start is this [Tutorial for Realm](https://medium.com/mindorks/realm-with-android-acf50ea68ece)

2. [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) - The official persistence library for Android. This may be a little advance but also has a good amount of community here at StackOverflow and has tons of online tutorial both from Google and other media.

For a tutorial, refer at this [Tutorial for Room](https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942)

3. [Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) -  There are other way to do this such as Shared Pref which I suggest to only store small amount of data such as username, userId and other small size objects.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can save objects either or on DB or shared preference

1. For cashing on DB you can use Android Room (SQLite) for tutorial you can check this
   link [room tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/android-room-tutorial/)
2. For caching objects on shared preference you can use below code

   ```
   public void saveObhect(UserModel userModel) {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String json = gson.toJson(userModel);
      prefsEditor.putString("USERMODEL", json);
      prefsEditor.commit();
   }


   public UserModel getYourObjModel() {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String json = sharedPrefs.getString("USERMODEL", "");
      Your obj = gson.fromJson(json, UserModel.class);
      return obj;
   }
   ```

Comment: If you are going to use a database, you might as well map the fields in `UserModel` directly to columns in the database table using an `@Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is primarily used to send data between two software systems. It can be used for storage as well, but isn't well designed for that purpose. This is because you have to store it in a flat file where you cannot easily search or filter the data. Instead you should look at databases for storing data.

Comment: how are objects stored in a data base?